# PHP MySql - doubles number of apostrophes while inserting and selecting data

Tags: php, mysql

When And Data is inserted into MySql containing apostrophe ('), it doubles itself.

Thus, if I try inserting

```
I'm
```

The value when checked via phpmyadmin becomes

```
I''m
```

Similarly on retrieving the data it becomes

```
I''''m
```

My Php Code is

```
$con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) ;
     // Check connection 
    //mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
    //mysqli_set_charset($con,'latin1_swedish_ci'); 
    //echo mysqli_get_charset($con);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    { 
        echo "Error";
        exit;
    }
      mysqli_query( $con , "SET character_set_results=latin1_swedish_ci");
    //echo mysqli_character_set_name($con);
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);   
    mysqli_close($con);
```

I have tried changing charset on tables and also on while I retrieve the data by above code. But still it keeps doubling apostrophes number.

Update :

When I execute same program on different server, it functions properly. Does this means it's a malfunction of my server side.

Comment: Helo,Where is your code for INSERTION ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function  before inserting.

```
$stringToStore= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$stringToStore);
```

And also retrieve value in PHP and echo that, to check is there any problem with php myadmin or not.

Comment: It's not because of SQL injection and I have used mysqli_real_escape_string as well. I'm getting unusual data not only while inserting data, but also on selecting data.

Comment: @Adarsh , Hi PDO should be used always since it doesnt require user to use real escape , and Coder can easily forget to use `escape_string` so better to go for PDO.

Comment: @JohnyPie in MySQL `'` can be escaped as (two quote `''`) OR (slash `\' `) both, that's may be the problem, but I have developed many project in which `'` working. Do it without escaping also and manually replacing `'` to `\'` by `str_replace` then insert. Try with/without PDO as @jQuery.PHP.Java.net suggested. Also show your insertion code.

Comment: @AdarshRajput you are unable to understand the situation. It's not at all related to escape, it's something related to charset. I have also updated the question stating, my code is perfectly fine on other server.

Comment: Then there may be ISSUES properly configuring mySQL on Your server.Getting?

Comment: @AdarshRajput Hello OP said same code exists on both servers.But on his server it uses two  `''` .There is nothing related to code here.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.JAVA.net exactly, that's what I mean. Do you know any common mistake ?